# Reusable Javascript components

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using jQuery's `slideToggle()` function in my web app.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

The HTML part is

```
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

My web app contains many such elements that have to be `slideToggled`. I want to write the JavaScript function only once and call it each time I need to implement the `slideToggle`. How do I go about it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the items a class and for example a data attribute then you can do

```
 $(function(){
    $(".flip").on("click",function(){
      $("#"+$(this).data("panelId")).slideToggle();
    });
 });
```

Using

```
<div class="flip" data-panelId="panel1">Click to slide the panel 1 down or up</div>
<div id="panel1">Hello world!</div>

<div class="flip" data-panelId="panel2">Click to slide the panel 2 down or up</div>
<div id="panel2">Hello world!</div>
```

If the item to toggle is always the next, then the code is

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fg7QG/)

```
 $(function(){
    $(".flip").on("click",function(){
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
 });
```

using this HTML where I give the panels a class too so I can hide them when the page loads using `.panel { display:none; }`

```
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel 1 down or up</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world 1</div>

<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel 2 down or up</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world 2</div>
```

Comment: Why is it working even if I don't write the data-panelId="panel1" for any of my elements. Coz your function is still working without the ID's. Can you please explain? The doubt is for the second piece of code.

Comment: The second piece takes all divs with class flip and when clicked, the flip whatever div come right after - see update

Comment: Got you. Now, which of the 2 methods will be better? The second one seems easier to understand. Will it raise any bugs? Is it safe?

Comment: the second one is completely safe assuming that the next element is the div you want to toggle. If not you need to do nextAll("div").first() for example. See my demo.

Comment: Will use the second one! Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a certain class that will be used for sliding the elements. Lets say

```
<div class="sliding otherclass">Text</div>
<span>Some text</span>
<ul class="sliding">
   <li>List one</li>
   <li>List two</li>
</ul>

<button>Show Them</button>
```

Now use

```
$('.sliding').click(function () {
   $(this).slideToggle();
})
```

This way, each element with class sliding will be toggled and others will be left as they are! Each of the class will be applied, but the function will run only when the class `sliding` is clicked. And the function will run only for the current element and not for others.

To view them back, use this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
   $('.sliding').slideDown();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/BC6T3/3/

Here is a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/BC6T3/1/

Comment: This was just an example brother! :) If you want, then I can add a button for that too..Should I ?? :) @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan, I have included that :) Ok now? :)

Comment: I downvoted for the toggling of the trigger. I keep the downvoting  because your first example is still there and is still wrong. Also your second example does not take OPs code into consideration at all. If he wanted a button he would have had one.

Comment: I have editted the code, its not the first one! :/ However, you have the same thing in your code. If you want to keep your answer on top, then good luck with that brother! :P I'm outta here..

Comment: It has nothing to do with keeping anything on top. Your jQuery still toggles .sliding regardless of the button - I do not see what I have in my code that I did not have when I wrote the answer an hour before you. I just now changed click to on("click" because it is considered better practice. I hope you can take constructive criticism without thinking I do this to get REP or something. PS Your second fiddle also toggles the trigger instead of the panel